# Is it possible to obtain an unique iCloud user ID on cocoa?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, ipad, icloud

My iOS app is currently on beta in TestFlight, and as a way to retribute to the nice people who helped me test it I would like to offer them some goodies such as, for instance, the full final version of the app for free.

For this, I was thinking of sending them a last beta version which would, automatically and upon execution, store some kind of ID from the logged in user into a VIP list I would keep online and then every next version of the app would check for their ID in order to verify if the user is a VIP user and unlock all the premium features.

Is it possible to obtain in the Cocoa apis a unique identifier that is associated to the user (as opposed to the device unique identifier)? I want this because I want to recognise the user in whatever device he installs it. I would like to avoid having to make my beta testers manually register as VIPs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using CloudKit. You'll need a `CKContainer`, and you'll ask it to fetch the user record ID. That record ID is unique for your apps, but is also stable for that user this means the same iCloud account will have the same record ID, regardless of which device they're running on or which of your apps they're using.

If you turn on the CloudKit capability for your project, Xcode will automatically create the iCloud container for you, and you can then access it using one of the two `CKContainer` constructors.

Comment: Just to let you know, yesterday I implemented the feature using CKContainer and it was super easy and exactly what I needed. Thank you again! :-D